# Encoding Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, encoding, apache-commons-lang

how could I convert a text escaped with StringEscpeUtils.escapeJavascript back to the original text  in java?
 I have converted a russian text with escapeJavascript and the result is:
\u041F\u043E\u0440\u043E\u0434\u044B,
but backwards it is not working.

Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

Try the unescapeJavascript method.

Answer (score 0):

You can try **native2ascii**, a **command line** tool in the bin directory of java. You need the original encoding.

The following alternatives try default encoding (your OS, `System.getProperty("file.encoding")`), Cyrillic, and Russian.

```
native2ascii -reverse input.txt output.txt
native2ascii -reverse -encoding windows-1251 input.txt output.txt
native2ascii -reverse -encoding KOI8-R input.txt output.txt
```

*Naturally in java you would simply print/write the string.Ä*